# How to put images on a localhost server

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, server, host

I am right now writing a program which grabs images from the internet and use them to start a server and write the html.

Here is my code:

```
import json 
import requests  
import urllib2
import webserver
import bottle
from bottle import run, route, request

#get images
r = requests.get("http://web.sfc.keio.ac.jp/~t14527jz/midterm/imagelist.json")
r.text
imageli = json.loads(r.text)
i = 1
for image in imageli:
    if i <= 5:
        fname = str(i)+".png"
        urllib.urlretrieve(image,fname)
        i += 1

#to start a server
@route('/')
#write a HTML, here is where the problem is,
#the content of html is <image src= "1.png"> but the picture is not on the server. 
#and I don't know how to do it
def index():   
    return "<html><head><title>Final exam</title></head><body> <img src=\"1.png\"/>\n <img src=\"2.png\"/>\n <img src=\"3.png\"/>\n<img src=\"4.png\"/>\n<img src=\"5.png\"/>\n</body></html>"
if __name__ == '__main__':        
    bottle.debug(True) 
    run(host='localhost', port=8080, reloader=True)
```

And I am having a problem that the images cannot be shown on the website, the console says images cannot be found.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is the problem the downloading or serving part? Please reduce the code you have problems with to the smallest possible example first. See also http://sscce.org.

Comment: You've saved the images locally, and have a bottle route which serves some HTML which links to them, but where is the code that actually serves the images?

Comment: The problem is that on the server, the images cannot be uploaded for it is saved locally. And I have just uploaded my codes

Comment: I have no idea what that comment means. I was simply pointing out that you do not seem to have anything that actually *serves* the images you have downloaded.

Comment: Sorry I will modify it once again

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you haven't defined a route for serving your static files. You could set the root directory to serve static files by adding this route:

```
# To serve static png files from root.
@bottle.get('/<filename:re:.*\.png>')
def images(filename):
    return bottle.static_file(filename, root='')
```

But you should really move these to a subdirectory, as in:

```
import json
import requests
import urllib
import bottle
from bottle import run, route, request

#get images
r = requests.get("http://web.sfc.keio.ac.jp/~t14527jz/midterm/imagelist.json")
r.text
imageli = json.loads(r.text)
i = 1
for image in imageli:
    if i <= 5:
        fname = "static/{}.png".format(i)  # Note update here
        urllib.urlretrieve(image, fname)
        i += 1

#to start a server
@route('/')
def index():
    return "<html><head><title>Final exam</title></head><body> <img src=\"1.png\"/>\n <img src=\"2.png\"/>\n <img src=\"3.png\"/>\n<img src=\"4.png\"/>\n<img src=\"5.png\"/>\n</body></html>"

# To serve static image files from static directory
@bottle.get('/<filename:re:.*\.(jpg|png|gif|ico)>')
def images(filename):
    return bottle.static_file(filename, root='static')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bottle.debug(True)
    run(host='localhost', port=8080, reloader=True)
```